# Is the Fourier transform of the reflection $f(-\cdot)$ equal to the reflection of the Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose that the reflection operator $A:L^2(\mathbb R) \to L^2(\mathbb R)$ is defined as $Af(x)=f(-x)$. Let $F : L^2(\mathbb R) \to L^2(\mathbb R)$ be the Fourier transform. Is it true that $A$ commutes with $F$?

Comment: Have you tried proving it?

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(-x) e^{ikx}\,dx\overbrace{=}^{x\mapsto -x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{i(-k)x}\,dx$$Does that answer the question?